# Installation of DOOPL

Tags: windows, makefile, doopl

I'm trying to install doopl from IBM github but I have the following error :

`make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/.../Documents/DOOPL/doopl-master/doopl-master/generate/x64_win' if [ ! -d 2211 ]; then mkdir 2211; fi ! était inattendu. make[1]: *** [makefile.build:76: generate] Error 255 make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/.../Documents/DOOPL/doopl-master/doopl-master/generate/x64_win' make: *** [../makefile:28: build] Error 2`

my makefile is :

```
########################################
COS_VERSION?= 2211
COSDIR?=C:/Users/DM9070/Desktop/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio2211
PYTHON_TARGET?= 3.8
PYTHON_HOME?= C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3
SWIGDIR?= C:/Users/DM9070/Documents/DOOPL/swigwin-4.1.1
#########################################


OPLDIR =C:/Users/DM9070/Desktop/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio2211/opl
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(OPLDIR)/bin/x86-64_linux
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(OPLDIR)/bin/x86-64_osx
#PATH=$(OPLDIR)/bin/x64_win64


all: build

clean:
    @echo ================================================
    @echo = Cleaning $(COS_VERSION)/$(PYTHON_TARGET)
    @echo ================================================
    $(MAKE) -f makefile.build COS_VERSION=$(COS_VERSION) PYTHON_TARGET=$(PYTHON_TARGET) OPLDIR=$(OPLDIR) clean

build:
    @echo ================================================
    @echo = Building for $(COS_VERSION)/$(PYTHON_TARGET)
    @echo ================================================
    $(MAKE) -f makefile.build COS_VERSION=$(COS_VERSION) PYTHON_HOME=$(PYTHON_HOME) SWIGDIR=$(SWIGDIR) PYTHON_TARGET=$(PYTHON_TARGET) OPLDIR=$(OPLDIR) install_in_src all
    @echo ================================================
    @echo = Sanity test run for $(COS_VERSION)/$(PYTHON_TARGET)
    @echo ================================================
    $(MAKE) -f makefile.build COS_VERSION=$(COS_VERSION) PYTHON_HOME=$(PYTHON_HOME) PYTHON_TARGET=$(PYTHON_TARGET) OPLDIR=$(OPLDIR) LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH) test
```

I tried to change the opl version and python version but it didnt work.Even with forward slashes, I have the same error.

Comment: You should always use forward-slashes in makefiles, not backslashes.  Make is a POSIX tool and doesn't "do" windows paths, in general.  I don't see how this can be your entire makefile because it doesn't DO anything, it just sets some variables.

Comment: I edit my question with the makefile and forward slashes

Comment: Please change the error output to use a code block, so that it is not reformatted and we can read the errors correctly.  I don't know what était inattendu means; unfortunately I have no French.  In any event, the makefile you've provided doesn't do anything except invoke make with the `makefile.build` makefile, and the error message is coming from the rule `makefile.build:76` (line 76 of that file) so that's where you have to look.  This recipe seems to be running POSIX shell commands so hopefully you have a POSIX shell installed and make is using that.